# Angular only update objects if it has been changed since last poll

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, leaflet

Im polling data from my web api to populate a map with markers. The markers has positions, and Im saving the markers in the following way

```
  allMarkers: Map<Number, Leaflet.Marker> = new Map();
```

At the moment I am refreshing the markers each time I poll my data, which is every 10 seconds. What I would like to do is to only refresh the markers who's position has actually changed. Is there any effecient way I can do that? I tried to use a "oldAllMarkers" and "newAllMarkers" but it didn't do much.

See my code below and please let me know if there is anything I should add to make things for clear.

---

```
// ngOnInit with a bunch of things. Here is where I set up my map and poll 
//  my data with the use of my subscribeToData function.
ngOnInit() {
    // Init map
    this.map = new Leaflet.Map('mapid', {}).setView([this.lng, this.lat], 10);
    this.tiles = new Leaflet.TileLayer(
      ,
      {
        attribution: `Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors,
           <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>,
           Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>`,
        maxZoom: 18,
        minZoom: 1,
        id: 'mapbox.streets',
        accessToken:

          }
        ).addTo(this.map);

    // init vehicles details
    this.store.select(fromStore.getAllVehicleDetails).subscribe(data => {
      this.vehicleDetails = data;


      this.setMarkers(this.selected);          

      // set the selected vehicle
      this.vehicleDetail = this.getVehicleDetail(this.selected);

      // set/refresh the markers
      this.setMarkers(this.selected);     

    });
    this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.LoadVehicleDetails());
    this.subscribeToData();
  }
```

---

```
 setMarkers(id: number) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.vehicleDetails.length; i++) {
      // Refresh markers
      if (this.allMarkers.get(this.vehicleDetails[i].id)) {
        const tempMarker = this.allMarkers.get(this.vehicleDetails[i].id);
        this.allMarkers.delete(this.vehicleDetails[i].id);
        if (tempMarker) {
          this.map.removeLayer(tempMarker);
          console.log('refresh map marker');
        }
      }

        // Creating the markers
        this.getIcon(this.vehicleDetails[i], status);

        // set markers to our hashpmap.
        if (this.markers) {
          this.allMarkers.set(this.markers.options.vehicleId, this.markers);
        }
     }
      // hide progress bar
      this.loading = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you implement ngOnChanges()?

Comment: Hey @wannadream ! Thanks for your reply. I've tried but it hasnt given me the expected result. Could you explain further in how you believe it could fix the problem?

Comment: Whenever value of 'allMarkers' changes, it will trigger ngOnChanges(). In the event handler, you can track changes and implement your code with old and new values.

Comment: API Reference: https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges